# Can I set different font size for different language?

Tags: fontsize

Some times I need to insert Chinese characters in my LaTeX documents and sometimes English letters.

I'd like English letters show in 12pt while Chinese characters show smaller(like 10pt or 11pt).

For example, I type the following line in .tex file.

```
English中文
```

And I'd like to see 'English' in 12pt and '中文' in 11pt.

Is there an easy way to make it?

------ edited ------

An easy way means, I do not want something like:

```
English{\small中文}
```

It makes me type `\small` every time when I type Chinese.

Comment: Do you use fontspec?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I just know this package, but I don't know how to use on my problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: it is very similar to the solution you have found

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer myself. But it may only work with Chinese, Japanese and Korean.

I use xeCJK for solving this problem.

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[scale=0.9]{Source Han Sans CN}
```

The document (written in Chinese) I checked is [mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf).

The font `Source Han Sans CN` is font I have on my Fedora Linux. You can use command `fc-list` in document pdf 3.2.1 for font selecting.

I am using `xelatex` for compiling thus `xeCJK` works well. If you use `pdfletex` for compiling, you may use:

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
```

And check its document.